# Is there a function similar to Sympy's solve that will take in an array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sympy, solver

I'm trying to solve a quadratic equation and I've had great success using Sympy's soler, but I want to solve for a changing value of a, b, and c (in the traditional format ax**2 + bx + c = 0) that I've set up as a numpy array.

I don't have extensive coding background... is there an easy way to do this?

for reference, this is my (messy,messy,messy) code. A is an array and it is a factor in a, b, and c. All the other variables are defined elsewhere.

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import solve, symbols

s = symbols('s')

psi = np.linspace(0,89,18)
A = 2 * C * eta / (1 + np.tan(psi) * np.tan(psi))

a = (A * ((vPsr*vPsr) - 2 * (vLat * vEarLat + vLon * vEarLon) + (vEar * vEar))) + (dist * wavelength * wavelength)
b = -2 * A * (vPsr * vPsr) + 2 * A * (vLat * vEarLat + vLon * vEarLon) - (dist * wavelength * wavelength)
c = A * (vPsr * vPsr)

answers = solve(a * s**2 + b * s + c, s)
```

Comment: You have to iterate through the elements of your arrays and at each iteration compute the solve(a[i]*s**2 + b[i]*s + c[i], s). Look at this page for further details http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html

Answer (score 1):

A general [quadratic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Discriminant), `a*x**2 + b*x + c = 0`, has two roots (that could be complex-valued) that are easily obtained with the expressions:

```
discriminant = b**2 - 4*a*c
root1 = (-b + sqrt(discriminant))/2/a
root2 = (-b - sqrt(discriminant))/2/a
```

Numpy can perform those 3 calculations easily and *for all elements at once* ("vectorized code") on your 3 arrays of coefficients `a`,  `b` and `c`, and it will go a *whole lot faster* than passing the equation to `sympy.solve` all the time.

To take into account the possibly complex nature of the roots, you could add zero times the complex unit to the discriminant to ensure numpy will not return a `nan` when taking the root of a negative number.

```
import numpy as np

# define your coefficient arrays a, b and c
discriminant = b**2 - 4*a*c + 0j  # added 0 time the complex unit
root1 = (-b + np.sqrt(discriminant))/2/a
root2 = (-b - np.sqrt(discriminant))/2/a
```

Those arrays, `root1` and `root2` are of equal length and each item will be the solution to your quadratic system defined by the coefficients in the corresponding elements defined in `a`,  `b` and `c`.